# How to declare the string variable to use overal project in asp.net

Tags: string, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

In my project I declare the one string like `public string str="dbname";`,
that string value use the overall application. 
Where can I declare that string?

Another problem is that I can change that string value after publishing the site in iis,
(or)
I am giving client that time also change the string value, so where I can declare the variable?

please give me any suggestion.

dbname is string value so i can chage that name after publishing or any time 
thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBName is something that belongs in a configuration file. ASP.NET uses files that are called web.config and they can store 'Connection strings', Application specific settings and other settings.

A configuration file can be edited after the program has been deployed to a production server. You can even automate this process so the settings are automatically set if you, for example, deploy to a test server, an acceptance or a production server.

[Here is some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx) about how to use configuration files.

Comment: You should also note that the application will typically get restarted if a change is made to the Web.Config file

Answer (score 0):

You have a client/server architecture?
You want your server application to use a global variable `str`?
You want your client application (which is a webinterface?) to change `str`?